# Generating a new Domain class with same fields as original Domain class in grails

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I have to save the old data to a history table whenever a field is changed in the current table. Hence, I have to create a history Domain class with same fields as original Domain class. For now, I am manually creating the history Domain class and saving the older data into it whenever the values are updated in the original table.
Is there a way to auto generate a history Domain class with same fields whenever a new Domain class is created.

Main Domain class is:

```
class Unit {

    String name
    String description
    Short bedrooms = 1
    Short bathrooms = 1
    Short kitchens = 1
    Short balconies = 0
    Short floor = 1
    Double area = 0.0D
    Date expDate
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [tenants:Tenant]
    static belongsTo = [property: Property]
}
```

History Domain class should be like this:

```
class UnitHistory {

    String name
    String description
    Short bedrooms = 1
    Short bathrooms = 1
    Short kitchens = 1
    Short balconies = 0
    Short floor = 1
    Double area = 0.0D
    Date expDate
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [tenants:Tenant]
    static belongsTo = [property: Property]
}
```

Comment: If your requirements are not 100% fixed, you may want to consider using an audit logging concept instead.  This will save you a lot of overhead especially for complicated objects (like hasMany tenants...are they all copied too?).  One existing plugin is here: http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/robertoschwald/audit-logging though there are certainly others as well.

Comment: Do you really need 2 separate domains or can you use the same one and version the records so the latest version always represents the current state and all the previous versions represent the history? (a separate version then the built in optimistic locking `version` property of course)

Comment: yes, hasMany is also copied. As per requirement, I must create another table with same fields with suffix "history". @JeffScottBrown

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` methods to your `Unit` domain as follows:

```
class Unit {

    String name
    String description
    Short bedrooms = 1
    Short bathrooms = 1
    Short kitchens = 1
    Short balconies = 0
    Short floor = 1
    Double area = 0.0D
    Date expDate
    Date lastUpdated

    def beforeInsert() {
        addHistory()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        addHistory()
    }

    def addHistory(){
        new UnitHistory( this.properties ).save( failOnError: true )
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I generate UnitHistory automatically whenever Unit is created. When any fields in Unit changes, it should be reflected in UnitHistory schema as well.

Comment: The above should achieve that

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know more about the actual requirements to know for sure what the best thing to do is but one likely solution to consider would be to use an event listener that would create instances of the history class each time an instance of the main class is inserted and/or updated.  At https://github.com/jeffbrown/gorm-events-demo/blob/261f25652e5fead8563ed83f7903e52dfb37fb40/src/main/groovy/gorm/events/demo/listener/AuditListener.groovy#L22 is an example of an event listener.  Instead of updating the instance like you see in that example, you could create a new instance of your history class, copy the relevant stuff and then persist that newly created history instance.

See https://async.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#gormEvents for more info about GORM events.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically generate the history class with same fields whenever a Domain class is created?